# Laravel 5.4 - Session closes thanks to a layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I am not sure how is this happening. On my landing page, I've got a simple statement that returns the user information by using the method "Auth::user()" and alas, it works.

Nevertheless, when applying a layout to my file, I get the "Trying to get property of non-object" exception. I've been playing with it a little then I made it so I can keep the session, but after reloading or moving to another page (which use the same layout, by the way), the session immediately closes itself.

What could be the issue behind this behaviour?

Update: I've found the problem. It seems to be this layout in particular which sets a navbar; it has an iframe that I thought was the problem, but when removing the iframe content (which is inside a modal, that I remove as well), the error keeps hapening - It closes the user's session and throws the exception.

```
@yield('nav')
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Printed</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Conóce</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contacto">Contacto</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Catálogo
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/productos">Productos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/servicios">Servicios</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Promociones</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Portafolio de Proyectos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      @if(Auth::check() == false)

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ingresar</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('login')}}">Iniciar Sesión</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('register')}}">Registrarse</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      @endif

      @if(Auth::check())

      <li class="nav-item">
          Hello, {{Auth::user()->email}} !
        </li>


      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Opciones</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Panel de Usuario</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{Auth::logout()}}">Cerrar Sesión</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endif
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Edit: Good news, I've discovered my issue. It seems to be this part in particular that somehow "triggers" itself. Could it be that I'm missing a closure on the tags somewhere?

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{Auth::logout()}}">Cerrar Sesión</a>
```

Comment: at least you show php code for the layout file?

Comment: I added the code for both files

Comment: which `guard` are you using, can you show your `auth.php`? and show your controller / middleware that authenticate user

Comment: Hello, I made a new change where I spot the problem. My auth, controllers, and middleware are the same that Laravel offers, I only made a change to the redirect to part.